# Discord.js Bot returning NaN on message send

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

so I'm trying to create this command that will allow me to make the bot message whichever channel I specify and then whatever I type after it took some working but I did get it to return a message in the correct channel but not what i am typing instead it is returning a 'NaN' whatever that means any ideas?

````
    let channelname = args.split(' ')[0];
    if(!channelname)
    {
      return message.say('Please provide a channel name.')
    }
    let say = parseInt(args.split(' ')[1]);

    message.delete() //deletes the message you sent
    const generalChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelname)
    generalChannel.send(say)
  }else{

  }
}
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `parseInt` the second element of the array.
If that is not a number you will get this error.

```
> parseInt("Hello")
> NaN
```

It should work if you simply remove the `parseInt`:

```
let say = args.split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: would you know how to go about joining the messages together after channel name as i can only find a way for it to post the one word after you specify channel

Comment: You mean something like: `const args = "channelname some long text"`?

This could be achieved as follows:

    `const splitted = args.split(' ') // split the array on space
    const channel = splitted.shift() // contains the first element of the splitted array
    // splitted now contains some long text`

Comment: Formatting is creepy on comments, hope you get the idea

Comment: i kinda get it ive tried to replicate what you are explaining and my bot just returns with 'd'

Comment: ive probably done this completely bonkers but     ```const splitted = args.split(' ')

    let channelname = args.split(' ')[0];
    if(!channelname)
    {
      return message.say('Please provide a channel name.')
    }
    let say = (splitted.shift(' ')[1]);```